# Can we upload file to google drive by React JS Directly?

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api

I want to upload files to Google Drive using React JS without using any intermediary server endpoint (Such as the Node API or Django Rest Framework). Please guide me if I have to create an intermediary endpoint or if I can upload files directly to Google Drive using React JS.

Comment: Whose "Google Drive" of `upload files to Google Drive` is in your situation? For example, do you want to upload a file to your Google Drive? Or, do you want to make users upload a file to each user's Google Drive? In the case of the former, I think that as a simple method, the service account might be able to be used. In the case of the latter, I think that first, it is required to prepare a script for making users login to each Google account and authorize the scopes.

Comment: I want to upload file only in my Google Drive

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussion.